# Creating type by reflection and passing by reference compiles but does not work

Tags: pointers, go, struct, reflection

When I dynamically create a pointer to a type and then pass it in to an unmarshalling function, it seems to be written correctly, in theory:

```
x := reflect.New(structType)
decode(x)
```

However, when you print `x`, it looks like the zero value of the type. The type is definitely correct and expected.

On the other hand, when I create the type and pass a pointer to it, directly, it works fine:

```
directoryEntry := DirectoryEntry{}
decode(&directoryEntry)
```

The contents are set correctly by `decode()` and, when printed, are correct.

So, it seems like I must be passing a value of the type to `decode()` and not a reference?

Can someone point out what I must be missing? A number of Google queries didn't help, and it seems like I must be missing something small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`reflect.New()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#New) returns you a pointer to a value of the passed type, but the returned pointer is wrapped in a [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) struct!

Use [`Value.Interface()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface) to "unwrap" it, and have a pointer as an `interface{}` which you can pass to `decode()`:

```
x := reflect.New(structType)
p := x.Interface()
decode(p)
```

When you print a `reflect.Value`, you often won't see a difference, because the `reflect.Value` type is treated special; quoting from [`Value.String()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.String):

> The fmt package treats Values specially. It does not call their String method implicitly but instead prints the concrete values they hold.

Comment: Yep. That makes sense (now). Works.